# ES2015 Destructure object twice in same scope

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

Is there a clean way to destructure the same variables from 2 similar objects in the same scope?

```
function(oldState, newState) {
  let {foo, bar} = oldState;
  // do stuff //
  let {foo, bar} = newState; // illegal double declaration in same scope
  {foo, bar} = newState; // illegal, not sure why
  let {foo: foo1, bar: bar1} = newState; // legal but ugly
  foo = newState.foo; // legal, but requires multiple lines
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can wrap the assignment in parens to reassign the variables via destructuring. The reason this is necessary is because otherwise the `{` is assumed by the parser to begin a block rather than an object literal or assignment pattern. [This blog post](http://whereswalden.com/2015/06/20/new-changes-to-make-spidermonkeys-and-firefoxs-parsing-of-destructuring-patterns-more-spec-compliant/) explains the situation in more detail.

```
function(oldState, newState) {
  let {foo, bar} = oldState;
  // do stuff //
  ({foo, bar} = newState);
}
```

Comment: Not that the `{...}` here do not denote an object literal either.

Comment: True, it's technically an `ObjectAssignmentPattern`, but the point remains that you're gonna have a bad time with anything in statement position that has a leading curly and isn't a block statement :)